# Counter from button click using PHP Class methods

Tags: php, class, methods

I have a simple program made that should increment the count of times you have clicked the button.

Here is my first php page:

```
    <title>Autolaskuri</title>
    <?php 
    require_once('Autolaskuri.class.php');

    $autolaskuri = new Autolaskuri();
    $autolaskuri->laskeLkm();
    $autolaskuri->teeLomake();
    $autolaskuri->naytaTulokset();
    ?>
```

and here is my class page:

```
    <?php
    class Autolaskuri {
    private $toyotalkm;
    private $nissanlkm;
    private $painike;

    public function __construct(){
    $this->$toyotalkm = $_POST['toyotalkm'];
    $this->$nissanlkm = $_POST['nissanlkm'];
    $this->$painike = $_POST['painike'];
    }

    public function laskeLkm(){
    if($this->painike == 'Nissan'){
        $this->nissanlkm = $this->nissanlkm + 1;
    } elseif($this->painike == 'Toyota'){
        $this->toyotalkm = $this->toyotalkm + 1;
    }
    else {
        $this->nissanlkm = 0;
        $this->toyotalkm = 0;
    }
    }
    public function teeLomake() {
    $lomake = <<<EOL
    <form method="post" action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}">
    <input type="hidden" value="{$this->toyotalkm}" name="toyotalkm">
    <input type="hidden" value="{$this->nissanlkm}" name="nissanlkm">
    <input type="submit" value="Toyota" name="painike">
    <input type="submit" value="Nissan" name="painike">
    <input type="submit" value="Nollaa" name="painike">
    EOL;
    echo $lomake;
    }

    public function naytaTulokset(){
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Number of Nissans: {$this->nissanlkm} ";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Number of Toyotas: {$this->toyotalkm}";
    echo "<br>";
    }

    }

    ?>
```

Whenever I click on either Nissan or Toyota the counter doesn't work and goes straight to the else statement since it shows 0. Have I assigned my variables wrong or what is the problem here?

Comment: name="painike[]"

Comment: `$this->$toyotalkm` shouldn't have the second `$` - you just need `$this->toyotalkm` to assign class properties.

Comment: I changed it but it still isn't working. I've been trying to get this right for so many hours now and it's getting frustrating. Do you have any idea why it's not working?

EDIT: IT WORKS! OMG IM SO HAPPY. It was really just that, thanks iainn!!

Comment: iainn you can write an answer for this question and @DidzisZvaigzne can accept it then

Comment: There shouldn't be spaces before `EOL;`. That is a 2nd issue. Enable error reporting and you'll see.